# How to Export Sql Server Result to an Excel Template using Python (starting in a defined cell)

Tags: python, sql, excel

I have a dataset from SQL (11 columns x 312 rows) that I'd like push onto a particular tab of an Excel template starting at a specific cell reference (A2) as row 1 contains headers. I have only ever been able to do this previously by creating a sort of 'feeder' Excel file from the SQL results first and then mapping those values from the feeder file into the excel cells of the template one by one. This would be very time consuming on the current requirement as I would need to write almost 3500 mapping statements.

Relatively new to Python so wondered if there was a way to 'bulk' populate a particular excel sheet with the SQL results in the template starting in cell A2. The column order in both the SQL results and template are obviously the same.

Thanks

Sam